# How can I move the SkyDrive folder?

Tags: windows-8, onedrive

I have installed the SkyDrive client for Windows 8, and it put the local folder in `C:\Users\Louis\SkyDrive`. My system drive is an SSD and I like to keep my documents on my D:\ drive which is an HDD.

I have tried to use the unlink account method, but it is not available to me:
[image: Unlink SkyDrive greyed out]

Without using symlinks, is it possible to move the SkyDrive folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wasn't able to move the folder, but by uninstalling SkyDrive and deleting the folder, then reinstalling SkyDrive I was able to select a different location during setup.

[image: SkyDrive folder location]

Answer (score 2):

1. Right click on OneDrive (as it is not called)
2. Properties
3. Select "Location" tab
4. Change to location you require the local folder to be

Once you change location, you will be asked if you wish to move all files.  I presume you will answer 'Yes'

Comment: Do you mean "as it is ***now*** called"?

Comment: Not sure if I should accept this, as my question was about Win8, but I'm now running 8.1 and can't check.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it manually:

First, in the SkyDrive setting, unlink your computer (right click on the SkyDrive icon on the taskbar and choose Settings, then Unlink SkyDrive)

Then move your C:\Users\Louis\SkyDrive folder to where you want it to be (D:\SkyDrive for example)

Finally, login to skydrive again. It will ask you for the skydrive folder location. point it to the new location

Comment: Hi, it seems this could work for other users, but it doesn't work for me. Please see my updated question.

Comment: then try logging out of your microsoft account in windows 8, sign in using a local account (create a temporary one if you need to) then sign in to skydrive again. I'm not sure if it works though